# Python Referencing Object Inside Object Incorrectly

Tags: python

I have 2 python classes: Player, and Board. The board contains a dict with "A1" reference style for spaces.

player.py's Player class:

```
from board import Board

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = input("Name: ")
        self.board = Board(3, ["A", "B", "C"])
```

board.py's Board class:

```
class Board:
    EMPTY = "0"
    spaces = {}
    def __init__(self, size, letters):
        for let in letters:
            for num in range(1, size + 1):
                self.spaces["{}{}".format(let, num)] = self.EMPTY

    def place_piece(self, spot):
        self.spaces[spot] = "X"

    def display_board(self):
        for let in letters:
            for num in range(1, size + 1):
                print("\n" + self.spaces["{}{}".format(let, num)]
```

When Player is instantiated, it creates a Board object inside.
2 players are created, and each is added to the list players[]. Each player's turn is selected with a simple 1/0 variable called current_player.

```
    from player import *
    from board import *

    current_player = 1
    players = []
    player_1 = Player()
    player_2 = Player()
    players.append(player_1)
    players.append(player_2)

    while True:
        # Switches players
        current_player = abs(current_player - 1)

        # Prints the current player's name
        print(players[current_player].name)

        # Calls some method which should alter the current player's board
        players[current_player].board.place_piece(input("> "))

        # Calls some method which should show the current player's board
        players[current_player].board.show_board()
```

Obviously, very simplified. The name prints out correctly every single time. The board, however, only uses the first player's board for both players. I know it's working because the players' name prints correctly.

The issue persists even if the boards are created separately and placed in their own list.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to put `Player` and `Board` classes in your question, and it would be better if you put `player.py` and `board.py` files here.

Comment: By files i meant content of files. Because you making `from <module> import *` which is [not good](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad).

Comment: And what `print("{} place a piece on your 
             board.".format(players[current_player].name)
        players[current_player].board.place_piece()` is that? Can you keep it as you have it in your code?  ALSO: what is that function `place_piece()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is written now the code posted shouldn't be working. The two methods in Board, `place_piece` and `display_board`, need to accept 'self' as a first argument.

Assuming this is a typo here's what's happening. The class Board is created with a *class member* `spaces`. Each time you're referencing `self.spaces` in an object, it is not found in the object is instead looked up in the class. Meaning **you're using the same dict for all object** of the class Board. Instead, to create a regular member place the declaration in the init method as you do in the Player class:

```
class Board:
    EMPTY = "0"
    # Remove spaces = {}

    def __init__(self, size, letters):
        self.spaces = {}
        ...
```

Finally, since you're using Python 2x please let me encourage you to always use new style classes (i.e. write `class Board(object)`). See [What is the difference between old style and new style classes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)

Comment: No $^#^$@ way. It was the `__init__():` issue. NEVER ONCE has that been told to me. If I ever meet you in real life, I'm buying you a pizza. My hat will forever stay off to you.

Comment: Haha, I'm glad I could help!